# Uniqueness of completion of dense totally ordered sets

Tags: order-theory

Let $(P, <)$ be a dense totally ordered set. Then there exists a complete totally
ordered set $(C,  \prec)$, such that:

1. $P \subseteq C$.
2. If $p,q \in P$ then $p<q \iff p \prec q$.
3. $P$ is dense in $C$.

Also $(C,  \prec)$ is unique up to an isomorphism over $P$.

I understand how to prove existence of the completion $(C, \prec)$
via the Dedekind cuts construction, but I don't know how to prove uniqueness
up to an isomorphism over $P$.

Comment: Have you shown that if $D$ is a Dedekind complete linear order, and $f:P\to D$ is an order embedding, then $f$ extends to an order embedding of $C$ in $D$? That’s the crucial tool.

Comment: No, I just started learning about these things, a lot of the terminology and reasoning is still foreign to me.

Comment: The set of rational numbers has 4 completions: $(-\infty,+\infty)$,  $\;[-\infty,+\infty)$, $\;(-\infty,+\infty]$, $\;[-\infty,+\infty]$. So if $P$ doesn't have both a maximum and a minimum element, not $\text{100%}$ true (just saying).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(C,\prec)$, $(C',\prec')$ be complete totally ordered sets s.t. 1-3 hold. Consider

$$
f \colon C \rightarrow C', \ c \mapsto \sup \{p \in P \mid p \prec c \},
$$
where the $\sup$ is calculated in $(C',\prec')$. (If $c$ is the least element in $(C,\prec)$, let $f(c)$ be the least element in $(C',\prec')$ and similar for maximal elements. Note that the density of $P$ guarantees that this goes through in every possible case.)

$f$ certainly respects the two orderings.

$f$ is injective: Given $c \prec d$ in $C$ fix $p \in P$ s.t. $c \prec p \prec q \prec d$. Then $f(c) \preceq' p \prec' q \preceq' f(d)$.

$f$ is surjective: Let $c' \in C'$. If $c'$ is the least element of $(C', \prec')$, there is nothing to do. Otherwise, as $P$ is dense in $C'$, we may write $c' = \sup X$ for some $X \subseteq P$ (calculated in $(C', \prec')$). Let $c := \sup X$ (calculated in $(C, \prec)$. Then by construction $f(c) = c'$.

This shows, that $f$ is the desired isomorphism.

Comment: If $f$ respects the two orderings, shouldn't that mean that $c \prec p $ implies $f(c) \prec' p$? Shouldn't the $<$ in the defintion of $f$ be a $\prec$? Also I don't understand what you mean by: "density of P guarantees that this goes through in every possible case"?

Comment: I corrected the typo. By the remark I simply mean that $f$ is well-defined: If $c$ is not the minimal element of $(C,\prec)$, density ensures that for every $d \prec c$ there is some $p \in P$ with $d \preceq p \prec c$, so that $c$ can be written as the supremum of some subset $X \subseteq P$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Also isn't the fact that $f$ respects orderings, i.e. $c \prec d$ implies $f(c) \prec' f(d)$ enough to prove injectivness of $f$?

Comment: To avoid confusion, I use $\sup$ to denote the supremum calculated in $(C,\prec)$ and $\sup'$ to denote the supremum calculated in $(C',\prec')$. As you said, $c'=\sup' X$ for some $X\subseteq P$. And we let $c:=\sup X$. I'm unable to get $f(c)=c'$ or $\sup' \{p \in P \mid p \prec c \}=c'$. Please elaborate on this!

Comment: @LeAnhDung Fix $X \subseteq P$. WLOG $\sup X \not \in P$. Then $f(\sup X) = \sup' \{p \in P \mid p \prec \sup X \} = \sup' \{p \in P \mid \exists x \in X \colon p \prec x \} = \sup'  \{p \in P \mid \exists x \in X \colon p < x \} = \sup'  \{p \in P \mid \exists x \in X \colon p \prec' x \}  = \sup' X$.

Comment: Oh I see, the gist is that for $p\in P$ and $X\subseteq P$, we have $$p \prec \sup X$$ $$\iff \exists x\in X: p\prec x$$ $$\iff \exists x\in X: p < x$$ $$\iff \exists x\in X: p \prec' x$$ $$\iff p \prec' \sup' X$$ Thus $f(\sup X) = \sup' \{p \in P \mid p \prec \sup X \} = \sup' \{p \in P \mid \exists x \in X \colon p \prec x \} = \sup'  \{p \in P \mid \exists x \in X \colon p < x \} = \sup'  \{p \in P \mid \exists x \in X \colon p \prec' x \}  = \sup'  \{p \in P \mid p \prec' \sup' X \} = \sup' X$.

Comment: Hi @StefanMesken, I think that your brilliant reasoning is applicable for $\sup X$ in general, not only $\sup X \notin P$. Could you please explain why you assume $\sup X \notin P$?

Comment: @LeAnhDung I just wanted the supremum to be a strict supremum so that I didn't have to worry about the difference between $\prec$ and $\preceq$.

Comment: @StefanMesken I'm unable to understand *...worry about the difference between $\prec$ and $\preceq$*. You can see that $\preceq$ appears nowhere in my previous comment. Is there anything wrong with my previous comment?

Comment: @LeAnhDung No, your comment is fine.

Comment: I'm sorry for doing hairsplitting, but can you elaborate on *...worry about the difference between $\prec$ and $\preceq$*?

Comment: @LeAnhDung If $\sup X \in P$, then it's not necessarily true that: $p \prec \sup X \iff \exists x \in X \colon p \prec x$. (Consider $p := \sup X$.) I think that's the only thing you need to be cognizant about here.

Comment: Hi @StefanMesken! But  we are consider $p \prec \sup X$, so how can $p := \sup X$ can happen?

Comment: @LeAnhDung $p$ is just a variable here. I'm not requiring $p \prec \sup X$ in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi @StefanMesken! I'm unable to understand why $(p \prec \sup X \iff \exists x \in X \colon p \prec x)$ is wrong, please elaborate more!

Comment: Hi @StefanMesken you wrote explicitly in your previous comment that *If 
$\sup X \in P$, then it's not necessarily true that: $p \prec \sup X \iff \exists x \in X \colon p \prec x$*.

Comment: I'm so confused!

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned Dedekind's completion of $P$. We can write it explicitly as $C=\{A\subseteq P\mid A\text{ is a proper, non-empty initial segment of }P\}$ ordered by inclusion, and $p\mapsto\{q\in P\mid q<p\}$ is the canonical embedding of $P$ into $C$.

Now suppose that $C'$ is another complete order with $P$ dense in $C'$, simply consider the map $\pi(c)=\{p\in P\mid p\prec_{C'}c\}$. And show that this is an isomorphism between $C$ and $C'$. Use the density of $P$ in $C$ and $C'$ for this.

This makes a slightly easier strategy than working with two abstract copies of an idea. Once you constructed one order like this, simply show that any other order is isomorphic to it.